# convert urls to clickable links

Tags: javascript, html

I searched tons of simmilar questions, but still don't know the solution. Some of them are too old...
Simple contenteditable div (or textarea) with urls inside.

```
<div id='story' contenteditable>
Lorem ipsum www.google.com. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask lorem ipsum.
</div>
```

Urls are mainly created via pasting them into text. I need to convert them into clickable links so I can store the new, clickable text into database.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need to convert before saving to DB? With php?
If so try this:

```
function replaceLinks($s) {
    return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.%-=#]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $s);
}

$s="Lorem ipsum www.google.com. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask lorem ipsum.";

echo replaceLinks($s);
```

The output will be:

```
Lorem ipsum www.google.com. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask</a> lorem ipsum.
```

Comment: What is `$s` argument? Entire text?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at my answer, I added full example.